# How to insert data in firebase using expo..?

Tags: react-native, expo

I've an issue, actually I want to insert data into firebase using expo from different screen(I'm using google auth in another screen and after completing it I'm going to main screen), it's working also but it is not saving data in which table I want it to store(after google auth, I'm saving data into firebase in 'users')..

// I'm using this code to insert data in first place (while login)

// and I'm also using isUserNew() method and it's working really fine..

```
    onSignIn = googleUser => {
    console.log('Google Auth Response', googleUser);
    // We need to register an Observer on Firebase Auth to make sure auth is initialized.
    var unsubscribe = firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(firebaseUser) {
      unsubscribe();
      // Check if we are already signed-in Firebase with the correct user.
      if (!this.isUserEqual(googleUser, firebaseUser)) {
        // Build Firebase credential with the Google ID token.
        var credential = firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
          googleUser.idToken,
          googleUser.accessToken
        );
        // Sign in with credential from the Google user.
        firebase.auth().signInAndRetrieveDataWithCredential(credential).then(function(result) {
          console.log('user signed in');
          if(result.additionalUserInfo.isNewUser){ 
            firebase.database().ref('/users/' + result.user.uid).set({
              gmail: result.user.email,
              profile_picture: result.additionalUserInfo.profile.picture,
              locale: result.additionalUserInfo.profile.locale,
              first_name: result.additionalUserInfo.profile.given_name,
              last_name: result.additionalUserInfo.profile.family_name,
              created_at: Date.now()
            }).then(function (snapshot){
              // console.log('Snapshot', snapshot);
            });
          }else{
            firebase.database().ref('/users/' + result.user.uid).update({
              last_logged_in: Date.now()
            });
          }
        }).catch(function(error) {
          // Handle Errors here.
          var errorCode = error.code;
          var errorMessage = error.message;
          // The email of the user's account used.
          var email = error.email;
          // The firebase.auth.AuthCredential type that was used.
          var credential = error.credential;
          // ...
        });
      } else {
        console.log('User already signed-in Firebase.');
      }
    }.bind(this));
  };
```

// This code is also showing an error that I can't call setState from an //unmounted component. 
// :- this function as well update() in firebase is in another screen or page.

```
async componentDidMount() {
    try {
      let {status} = await Permissions.getAsync(Permissions.LOCATION);
      if(status !== 'granted'){
        const {status} = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.LOCATION);
      }else{
        const watchId = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(
          ({ coords : {latitude, longitude} }) => this.setState({latitude, longitude}, () => console.log('State:', this.state)),
          (error) => this.setState({ error: error.message }),
          { enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 0, maximumAge: 1000, distanceFilter: 1},
        );
        await AsyncStorage.setItem('LiveFeedId', JSON.stringify(watchId));
      }
    }
    catch(err) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  };

/* when I'm using this code it's saving the data but not in 'users' table in  firebase */

firebase.database().ref('users/').update({
   latitude: latitude,
   longitude: longitude,
});
```

Can anyone please help me out here, I'm really new to react native..
And I want to update my latitude and longitude from another screen to firebase where I've saved my users details, ex:- 'firebase.database().ref('/users/' + result.user.uid)'..

Thanks

Comment: Expo has nothing to do with writing data into firebase

Comment: Did you check your firebase rules ? It might prevent you to write data

Comment: Yeah I've checked and It's working fine but I while updating data from another screen I want to store data in logged in user's uid.. and that is not happening.

Comment: by the thanks for replying.

Comment: I will try to be more clear about my problem.., Actually when I'm updating my data then it is storing in 'users' directory inside firebase ex:- firebase.database().ref('/users/').update({ somedata: somedata });

Comment: But while login I'm using google authentication using Firebase and it's working great and it's saving my data inside firebase in some specific 'uid' for ex:- firebase.database().ref('/users/' + result.user.uid).set({ data: result.user.uid });

Comment: So what I'm asking here is that how can I update my data in specific 'uid' ('/users/' + result.user.uid) because when I'm trying this code for ex:- firebase.database().ref('/users/' + result.user.uid).update({ somedata: somedata });

Comment: In another screen it shows undefined variable result error. So Please help me in here that how can I update data from another screen when user is logged in because I'm able to fetch the data for ex:- {firebase.auth().currentUser.displayName}     But I want to insert data from another screen inside same 'uid' (user logged in).

Comment: Please put these details in your question, not comments

Comment: I've already mentioned my problem in my question Sir..